# I have a question about using Shared_Preferences in flutter when I build apk and install

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

Hi I have a problem while using **Shared_Preferences** in Flutter.

When the apk was downloaded and executed for app Release,**'Missingpluginexception'** occurred in the Shared_Preferences Library.

So to solve this,**'SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});'** was inserted into the main function.

Then, every time the app is run, there is a problem that the values ​​previously saved through Shared_Preferences are not remembered and reset.

While searching for a problem, I saw a solution to add some code to MainActivity.java, but my project doesn't have this, only MainActivity.kt exists.

How can you solve the problem in this situation?

This is 'MainActivity.kt'

```
package com.example.mryr

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check that you are using the latest version in your project.
The SharePreferences plugin must be instantiated in order to use it.

To save the value you must define a key that is going to be with which you will be able to obtain the value when you want to recover it.
This is the example that comes on your [page](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences).

```
_incrementCounter() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;
  print('Pressed $counter times.');
  await prefs.setInt('counter', counter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never had to touch Java or Kotlin files in order to user Shared_Preferences before. Just make sure you have the latest version as a dependency in `pubspec.yaml`, and that every time you are going to use it, you need to create an instance of it in your function, such as:
 `SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();`

a Little Example:

```
  /// Save your values using shared preferences
  _valueSaver(int value) async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    /// you may use setInt, setString, setBool, or setDouble to save anything you need
    preferences.setInt('myKeyName', value);
  }
  
  //Retrieve the values in a new function/class/wherever you need
  _valueGetter () async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //Then use get<whatever you saved> to retrieve
    int value2 = preferences.getInt('myKeyName');
  }
```